# transform data from mysql to hbase

Tags: java, mysql, hbase

I want transform my data tables from MySql database into HBase.
I will do it with java codes.

So I select tables from mySql but i cannot found how  put them row by row in tables in hbase.

Is there any way for doing it?
I will not do this via importing Tsv file  or bulk file.
please help me.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nosql-databases/kQsdYEsDUjs

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make use of **[Sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org/)**? It's convenient and efficient as it is based on MapReduce thus performs the data transfer in a distributed fashion.

If you don't want to use Sqoop you can achieve that through MapReduce directly(I am assuming your data is really big since you are considering HBase. So MapReduce will definitely be a better choice than normal Java programs). To do that you can use **[DBInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/db/DBInputFormat.html)**. Once you have read the data using DBInputFormat you can put it into your HBase tables using **[TableOutputFormat](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableOutputFormat.html)**.

And yes, you can also do that through normal Java programs. But that would be an overkill, IMHO.

HTH

Comment: thanks for your answer. before I try use sqoop but i have problem for config it.as you say i want use mapreduce and i hope it work.thanks a lot Tariq.